My supabase API key is not importing in Nextjs application (No API key found in request)
I am working on Nextjs project with supabase client, when am trying to make api call to supabase client it show Unauthorize message.
Supabase Create Client Code:
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
const supabaseUrl = 'https://elkiggqnkibjbzgdfqrx.supabase.co'
const supabaseKey = process.env.NEXT_SUPABASE_API
export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, `${supabaseKey}`)

Env file:
NEXT_SUPABASE_API=<supabase_key>

Client Error:
POST https://elkiggqnkibjbzgdfqrx.supabase.co/rest/v1/earlybird 401 (Unauthorized)
I try to access the supabase client object and make api calls to the postgress database which I gave the policy.
Database Policy:
alter policy "Enable insert for anon key only"
on "public"."earlybird"
to anon
with check (
  true
);

The policy affect a database table with only {email}.
Table:



id
email
create_at




0
email
datetime


..
.....
.........




Following the quickstart guide (https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/quickstarts/nextjs), you should prefix the env keys with NEXT_PUBLIC_ so it's available for the browser (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser)

It did helped, thanks
